# Turning to variables into one based on logical criteria

Tags: r, variables, aggregate, mutated

I have this dataframe that consists of three variables: `id, wwb and ub_bene`

```
       id   wwb ub_bene    
    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 800009     0       0
 2 800009     0       1
 3 800009     1       0
 4 800009     1       0
 5 800009     0       0
 6 800015     0       0
 7 800015     0       1
 8 800015     0       0
 9 800015     1       0
10 800015     0       1
11 800033    NA      NA
12 800033    NA      NA
13 800042     0       0
14 800042     0       1
15 800042    NA      NA
```

However. Im looking for some way to turn these variables into one, so that:

If `wwb = 1`, then column C will be 2, and if `ub_bene = 1`, then column C will be 1 and otherwise 0.

This is what I want to obtain:

```
       id   wwb ub_bene  c
    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> 
 1 800009     0       0   0
 2 800009     0       1   1
 3 800009     1       0   2
 4 800009     1       0   2
 5 800009     0       0   0  
 6 800015     0       0   0
 7 800015     0       1   1
 8 800015     0       0   0
 9 800015     1       0   2
10 800015     0       1   1
11 800033    NA      NA   NA
12 800033    NA      NA   NA
13 800042     0       0   0
14 800042     0       1   1
15 800042    NA      NA   NA
```

Any easy solution to obtain this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a nested `ifelse`:

```
df$c <- ifelse(df$wwb == 1, 2, ifelse(df$ub_bene == 1, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply just a simple math on the columns like,

```
df$c <- df[,2] *2 + df[,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating sums of the cumsums, using `matrixStats`.

```
matrixStats::rowSums2(matrixStats::rowCumsums(dat[2:3] == 1))
# [1]  0  1  2  2  0  0  1  0  2  1 NA NA  0  1 NA
```